# call a web service , by an action button with angular , from nodeJS server ,

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, api

want to call a rest API from a nodeJS server with a click of a button in my project angular to add a user in the database, the api in the server is connected to my mysql database , just i wonna invoke the api rest of add ou update ou delete from the button in my project angular . I am new to this I dont know how to proceed.
thank you

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SmartTableData } from '../../../@core/data/smart-table';
//import { EmailValidator } from '@angular/forms';


@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-smart-table',
  templateUrl: './smart-table.component.html',
  styles: [`
    nb-card {
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
  `],
})

@Injectable()
export class Configuration {
    public server = 'http://localhost:3000/';
    public apiUrl = 'api/';
    public serverWithApiUrl = this.server + this.apiUrl;
}



export class SmartTableComponent {

  settings = {
    add: {
      addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
      createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
      actionButonContent:'<i (click)="makeServiceCall($event)"><i/>',
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
      actionButonContent:'<i (click)="onEditConfirm($event)"></i>'
    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true,
      actionButonContent:'<i (click)="onDeleteConfirm($event)"></i>'
    },
    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'ID',
        type: 'number',
      },
      firstName: {
        title: ' Name',
        type: 'string',
      },
      email: {
        title: 'E-mail',
        type: 'string',
      },
      password: {
        title: 'password',
        type: 'password',
      },
    },
  };
  source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();
  constructor(private service: SmartTableData) {
    const data = this.service.getData();
    this.source.load(data);
  }
  onDeleteConfirm(event): void {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my app.js (server)

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var user=require('../model/user');

router.get('/:id?',function(req,res,next){


if(req.params.id){

user.getUserById(req.params.id,function(err,rows){

if(err)
  {
  res.json(err);
  }
  else{
  res.json(rows);
  }
  });
 }
 else{

user.getAllUsers(function(err,rows){

if(err)
  {
  res.json(err);
  }
  else
  {
  res.json(rows);
  }

 });
 }
 });
 router.post('/',function(req,res,next){

user.addUser(req.body,function(err,count){
  if(err)
  {
  res.json(err);
  }
  else{
  res.json(req.body);
  }
  });
 });
 router.delete('/:id',function(req,res,next){

user.deleteUser(req.params.id,function(err,count){

if(err)
  {
  res.json(err);
  }
  else
  {
  res.json(count);
  }

});
 });
 router.put('/:id',function(req,res,next){

user.updateUser(req.params.id,req.body,function(err,rows){

if(err)
  {
  res.json(err);
  }
  else
  {
  res.json(rows);
  }
  });
 });

 module.exports=router;
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a call you need to add the HttpClientModule in your app.module.ts as import.

Then inject the Http client it wherever you want to use it:

`constructor(private http: HttpClient){}`

to use it just do:

`this.http.get(<<url>>) //for get request
 this.http.post(<<url>>,obj) //for post request`

this returns an observable from which you can map the results and catch errors using Rxjs operators. for eg

```
addUser(user){ //called on button click
    this.http.post(yourUrl,Json.Stringify(user)).pipe(
      map((res)=>{
         //do something with response
         return 'sucess'
        }),
      catchError(err => {
        //handleError
      }
    ).subscribe(); // dont forget to subscribe
    }
```

if you want to learn more : https://angular.io/guide/http
and for rxjs: https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the data that needs to be sent to the server is being passed to the function as the "data" parameter. Add "HttpClientModule" to the main app module or to your custom module if any as follows. Custom service has been imported in the app module or import it in your module accordingly.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomService } from 'location-of-custom-service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [CustomService]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Create a service file as follows.

**custom.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomService {

   public server = 'http://localhost:3000/';
   public apiUrl = 'api/';
   public serverWithApiUrl = this.server + this.apiUrl;

   private fetchDataURL = this.serverWithApiUrl + 'fetchSomeData'; 
   private addDataURL = this.serverWithApiUrl + 'addSomeData' 


  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  // Fetch data
  fetchData(id): Observable<any> {
    this.fetchDataURL = this.fetchDataURL + "/" + id;
    return this._http.get<any>(this.fetchDataURL, httpOptions)
     .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
     );
  }

  // Add data
  addData(data): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post<any>(this.addDataURL, data, httpOptions);
  }

 // Error handler - you can customize this accordingly 
 handleError(error) {
   let errorMessage = '';
   if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
     // client-side error
     errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
   } else {
     // server-side error
     errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
   }
   return throwError(errorMessage);
 }
}
```

Your existing component has been modified so as to have the new additions as follows.

**smarttable.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomService } from './custom-service-location';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-smart-table',
  templateUrl: './smart-table.component.html'
})

export class SmartTableComponent  implements OnInit {

    constructor(private customService: CustomService) {}
    fechedData: any;

 // you existing codes goes here

    // Add data - assume the data that needs to be sent to the server is as "data"
    makeServiceCall(data) {
        this.customService.addData(data)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            // your logic after data addition goes here
          },
          (error) => {
              // logic to handle error accordingly
          });
    }

    // Fetch data
    getData(id) {
        this.customService.fetchData(id)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.fechedData = data;
            // your logic after data fetch goes here
          },
          (error) => {
              // logic to handle error accordingly
          });
    }
}
```

I hope the above helps.